# apt-get update error ubuntu 12.04 to version 14

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

i can't run an update from ubuntu 12.04 to 14, during the update process i got souces error. But my network seems to be ok. How can i fix it?

I did the update on my laptop, but i can't do it on my desktop :/

> W:Impossible de récupérer
>   http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP : 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
>   (...)
>   404  Not Found [IP : 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80] , W:Impossible de
>   récupérer
>   http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/universe/binary-armhf/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP : 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80] , E:Le téléchargement
>   de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les
>   anciens ont été utilisés à la place.

Comment: What do `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` say?

Comment: it returns "amd64" for the first command and "i386
armhf" for the other.

Answer (score 0):

To do a release update on ubuntu you need to run `sudo do-release-upgrade` as `apt-get update` just refreshes the sources for packages and `apt-get upgrade` just updates all packages to the latest version, but doesn't update to the latest ubuntu release.

Comment: i tried sudo do-release-upgrade, and the other way with the graphical update manager. The update stopped because of mysterious network errors in both case.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Ubuntu repositories for the *armhf* architecture. To upgrade, you need to disable the support for this arch during the release upgrade.

1. Find out, what packages built for *armhf* you have installed: `dpkg -l | grep armhf`
2. Uninstall these packages, if there are any. They cannot be upgraded automatically.
3. Remove *armhf* from the multiarch system: `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf`
4. Do the upgrade: `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Optional, if you still need the software you just removed:

5. Readd the *armhf* architecture: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf`
6. Install the *armhf* software you removed. (The same way you installed it before.)

Comment: there is no armhf packages left. finally i succefully the upgrade. but the apt-get update still returns 404 errors

Comment: The same errors? The ones according the `main/binary-armhf/` tree?

Comment: the errors begginig with  http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty

Comment: Did you add the `armhf` arch after the upgrade? If you don't need it, leav it away.